Version mismatch on nginx.pm after updating nginx module perl
I have gotten an error after updating nginx on my server, the module Perl in the file /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34.0/nginx.pm says its version is 1.24.0 but I have an error that reads:
[alert] 55475#55475: version 1.26.1 of nginx.pm is required, but 1.24.0 was found

I discovered that I have another nignx.pm file at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34/nginx.pm with the correct version specified, but I have no idea how to get nginx to use that over the one it has been using.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Version specs:
nginx version: nginx/1.26.1
This is perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

You have to remove your /usr/local version.  That version in /usr/local supersedes the system-installed versions.

According to Thomas Ward's comment the solution was to remove the file at
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34.0/nginx.pm

Which appeared to have worked.
